# Use the right hand Riemann sum with $n = 5$ to approximate the integral.

Tags: calculus, riemann-sum

Consider $\int^{10}_0x^2g'(x)dx$ where g has the values in the following table.

\begin{array}{r|l|l|l|l|l}
x& 0 & 2 &4 & 6 & 8 & 10\\\hline
g(x) & 2.9 &3.7 & 5.2&6.5&6.6&7.5
\end{array}

Q: $\int^{10}_0x^2g'(x)dx$ ≈ ?

My Try:
Using integration by-parts then I got

$x^2g(x)|^{10}_0-\int^{10}_02xg(x)dx$

And then what I am confusing is how to use Riemann Right Hand Sum to plug the number into the equation I got above?

Comment: The integration by parts was the right idea. Now for $x=2$ to $10$ compute $2xg(x)$, and you are in familiar territory. Here $\Delta x=2$.

Answer (score 1):

Well for the first term, you just have to substitute in the values at $x = 0$ and $x = 10$. The second term, you'd then write the integral as a Riemann sum:

$$\int_0^{10} 2xg(x)\ dx \approx \sum_{x = 2}^{10}\left ( 2xg(x) \times 2\right )$$

since you're evaluating over rectangles of width 2 (given that's the spacing you have for values of $g(x)$ and height equal to the function within the integral, evaluated at the right-hand side of the rectangle).

Comment: So for second term should be (2*2*3.7*2)+(2*4*5.2*2)+(2*6*6.5*2)+(2*8*6.6*2)+(2*10*7.5*2)=780. And use first term 750-780=-30. Riemann sum is the sum area of serval rectangles area? Why the answer is negative?